# Ruby Active Record joins and includes generate different sql for count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Here are my tables:

```
User
id:          primary key
user_name:
role_id:     foreign key     **NOT NULL**
```

--

```
Role
id:          primary key
name:
```

I am executing the following statements with Active Record:

**Statement 1:**

```
User.includes(:role).size
   (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
```

**Statement 2:**

```
User.joins(:role).size
   (1.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "roles" ON "roles"."id" = "user"."role_id"
```

Based on the fact that:

1. The foreign key role_id is not null
2. Taking count(*) without join has better performance and resource usage

I am very puzzled why do this two queries generate different SQL. And being more precise why the join generate SQL with poorer performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveRecord is simply not that smart. By calling

```
User.joins(:role).size
```

you are telling it to `INNER JOIN` the `roles` table and then check the count.

It uses the `INNER JOIN` even for the count, because it's not smart enough to figure out that since you have a foreign key **AND** the column is not nullable **AND** there are no conditions on `roles` table, the join isn't really needed.

Calling

```
User.includes(:role).size
```

does not generate the join because you're not telling ActiveRecord to load all Users that do have a role defined and it uses left joins or separate queries to load the roles.

Comment: You´re making a faulty assumption that the two queries are equivelent. They are not since they can have different results. The inner join generated by `User.joins(:role).size` will only return rows with a match in the `roles` table while `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"` will return any row from the `users` table.

Comment: The assumption is correct in this case as it is mentioned in the question that there is a foreign key that is not nullable, which was the basis for asking the question.

Comment: Ah, I missed the not nullable part.